# Cathode region in corrosion

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

The anode region is on the iron where the following reaction occurs: 
$$\ce{Fe(s) -> Fe^2+(aq) + 2e-}$$

and at the cathode region, the following reaction occurs
$$\ce{O2(g) + 4H+(aq) + 4e- -> 2H2O(l)}$$

However, the textbook does not explicitly state what the cathode region is. Can someone provide an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the cathode region is a source of $\ce{O2(g)}$, which is probably the **air** in contact with the iron. Therefore the reacting should occur at the interface iron/air.

Comment: There's a pretty good diagram of the process [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/chemical/corrosion.html). Where the reduction reaction actually occurs basically depends on where the oxygen can reach the metal.